# NodeJS Require cannot find module

Tags: node.js, azure, npm

I'm using VS 2015 for developing NodeJS console applications.

I have just created a new project from ExpressApp template.
I wanted to use 'azure-storage' packages in code.

I installed using the npm wizard VS 2015 offers and I can see the package installed in the Solution explorer under 'npm'.
Yet, I cannot require:

```
import azure = require('azure-storage');
```

Saying:

> cannot find module 'azure-storage'
>
> cannot find external module file by specified path.

You can see this in the attached picture.

Here's what I did following these two posts:
[post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047030/nodejs-cannot-find-module) [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364728/cannot-find-module-nodejs)
What can I do else?
thanks

Comment: Check the `node_modules` folder and make sure the lib did actually install correctly. If it's there, delete the folder & rerun `npm install` just to be sure. Also, I'm not familiar with the `import` keyword in Node, is that an ES6 feature? In ES5 you would do `var azure = require('azure-storage')`.

Comment: It's a typescript syntax for what you meant. I already did what you suggested, it did not solve my problem. The libs are there

Comment: in that case I'd question the lib name, what does your package.json look like? Do you have an npm link to the package you are using?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
```

Comment: if you are importing a typescript library, yes. You seem to be trying to add a JavaScript library which needs to be var since it won't be compiled until runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is not an official azure sdk for typescript present. And `import` in typescript just can import typescript modules.

you can try to leverage the TypeScript type definitions to allow `require` function in typescript.
This solution leverages this answer of [Importing node-modules with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378503/importing-node-modules-with-typescript) on SO. Code sample should like:

`///<reference path='node.d.ts'/>
var azure = require('azure-storage');`

Be the way, this group has transferred azure sdk for node to typescript https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/node-azure which you can try to use directly in typescript. But the version of this sdk is a little out of date.

Answer (score 0):

In new version you can defined like this.

```
import  * as azure  from 'azure-storage';
```